# How to create a link (url) to an calendar event per google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

currently I try to create a script which is list all my calendar-event in GSheet. For this job I have create a running script. I want to add an additional column with the direct URL-Link to the event.

Does anyone can help ans spend me a scriptexample. Here you can find the link to my example-GSheet-file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yVQ9JFw2XFftMBJPYWICHNAYvnpwcIleeStiBIiSx0Y/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another variation of @Vetx answer which includes encoding of event id and calendar id and uses a different base url (I optimized your current code by writing the data in your sheet only once)

### Sample Code:

```
function myStart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MyCalendar");
  var myEMail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  sheet.clear();
  var data = [["Start","End","Headline","I am the owner","Creator","URL"]]

  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 100);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 100);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 300);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 150);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(5, 250);
 
  var myCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(myEMail).getEvents(new Date(1900,1,1), new Date(2100,1,1));

  for (var i=0;i<myCal.length;i++) {
    var txt = myCal[i].getCreators();
    if (myEMail == txt) {

      var eventID = myCal[i].getId();
      // Remove succeeding characters after @
      eventID = eventID.substr(0, eventID.indexOf("@"));
      // Combine event id and calendar id (with space in between)
      var str = eventID + " " + myEMail; 
      var encode = Utilities.base64Encode(str).replace("=","");
      var link = "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=" + encode
   
      var tmpData = [
        myCal[i].getStartTime(),
        myCal[i].getEndTime(),
        myCal[i].getTitle(),
        myCal[i].isOwnedByMe(),
        myCal[i].getCreators(),
        link
      ];

      data.push(tmpData);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Add header row values in the `data` variable
2. Get all events based on the given calendar id, start and end date
3. Parse the event id (remove trailing characters after @) and combine it with the calendar id. Encode the string and append it to the base url `https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=`
4. Push each event processed to `data` variable
5. Write the data to the sheet

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect it is working. I just had to check the logic behind it and I must replace:
"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid="
to
"https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit/"

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will create a calendar link in the current cell of Sheet0

```
function createCalendarEventLink(id = 'MGk3dHJrMTJiZzBka2hrMnNtdDRhZGZ0YWEgamltZXN0ZWJhbkBqaW1lc3RlYmFuLmNvbQ') {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');//edit sheet name
  const url = `\"https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit/${id}?tab=mc\"`;
  const label = '"Calendar Event Link"'
  let f = `=HYPERLINK(${url},${label})`;
  sh.getCurrentCell().setFormula(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not as smooth as Cooper's solution. But it solved the encoding Base64 problem of the eventID for me.

```
function calendar() {

  var start = new Date(2021,7,8)
  var end = new Date(2021,9,9)

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()).getEvents(start, end)

  for (var i = 0; i <= cal.length; i++){
    var eventID = cal[i].getId() 
    var eventIDshort = eventID.substr(0, eventID.length - 11)
    var calID = String(cal[i].getOriginalCalendarId()).substr(0,cal[i].getOriginalCalendarId().length - 9)
    var str = eventIDshort + " " + calID + "m"
    var encode = Utilities.base64Encode(str)

    var link = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit/" + encode //This is the Link you want
  }
}
```